# Verbe pronominal en présence d'un adjectif, en fonction des parties du corps ?

Tags: grammaire, possessif

Extrait de la page 106 de *Advanced French Grammar* de V Mazet :

> 1. Elle a coupé ses beaux cheveux. = *She cut her beautiful hair.*
>
> If the sentence has a subjective adjective, use the possessive with a part of the body. You can't use a reflexive verb in this type of sentence. If there were no adjective in this sentence, we'd have **2. elle s'est coupé les cheveux**.

Questions :

I. Quelles sont exactement ces règles qui changent selon la présence ou l'absence d'un adjectif ? Par simplicité, pourquoi ne pas s'en tenir à une seule d'entre elles ?

II. Dans « Elle a coupé ses beaux cheveux. », est-ce les cheveux sont à elle dans le sujet de la phrase ? Ou a-t-elle coupé les beaux cheveux d'une autre femme ? Comment déduire la bonne personne ?

---

De par le commentaire de Circeus, je voudrais m'enquérir de
**3. elle s'est coupé ses beaux cheveux** ? Prière de faire les points communs et divergences entre 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: 1/ A nouveau, les règles décrivent l'usage et il ne faut pas chercher trop loin des raisons parce qu'on en arrive a penser que les règles déterminent l'usage, ce qui est visiblement faux.  Suggérer qu'on puisse changer les règles pour changer les usages -- même dans le cas d'une règle aussi propre à l’écrit que l'accord du participe passe -- est inutile.  2/ Seul le contexte permet de lever l’ambiguïté.

Comment: Un adjectif fait souvent office de déterminant, et ce n'est pas permis dans une tournure verbale telle que « se couper les cheveux » ; malgré l'article défini, *les cheveux* est un complément indéterminé qui n'est relié au sujet que par le verbe, et ce complément doit rester indéterminé.

Answer (score 2):

1) Dans l'absolu, la phrase *"Elle s'est coupé les beaux cheveux."* **aurait pu** être admise et être une formulation possible, mais ça n'a vraisemblablement pas été le cas, et l'usage a retenu l'autre manière de placer l'adjectif. C'est un choix arbitraire, qui n'a pas d'explication strictement logique.

2) Il y a effectivement une ambiguité possible avec la formulation *Elle a coupé ses beaux cheveux*, mais qui sera résolue sans difficulté d'après le contexte. (Je vois assez mal cette phrase se promener toute seule.)

Comment: Suis-je le seul pour qui *elle s'est coupé **ses** beaux cheveux* est grammaticalement correct (quoique pas particulière élégant)?

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Pourriez-vous éclaircir votre réponse à ma Qn 1 que **elle s'est coupé les cheveux** est grammaticalement exacte mais n'est point employé actuellement ? Par contre, est-il possible en fait de dire n'importe laquelle des 2 ?

Comment: La phrase **elle s'est coupé les cheveux** est très fréquemment employée, c'est la forme la plus courante. La phrase devient incorrecte (pour des raisons expliquées dans la réponse ci-dessus) quand on ajoute l'adjectif : **elle s'est coupé les beaux cheveux**. Donc on dit **elle s'est coupé les cheveux** mais **elle s'est coupé ses beaux cheveux**.

Comment: @Lamine: pour la dernière phrase, je dirais simplement « elle a coupé ses beaux cheveux ».

Comment: +1 a la reponse et les commentaires. J'ajouterai que pour moi (un anglophone) : Dans "elle a coupe un ongle" ce qui est important c'est vraiment l'action et l'objet ongle (et sans ajouter d'autre precision, on ne sait meme pas s'il s'agit d'un ongle a elle). Dans "elle s'est coupe les ongles" le vrai objet est elle, le sujet, et les ongles ne font que preciser ou qualifier l'action qu'elle fait a elle-meme. Utiliser la verbe de facon reflexive souligne l'importance du sujet et enleve de l'importance a l'objet direct (les ongles).